# Как в Excel удалить все символы, кроме цифр?

Tags: excel

Как в Excel удалить из телефонного номера все лишние знаки? Такие как: точка, дефис, кавычки и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагая что номер лежит в A1 (упоминается в двух местах):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$25),1))
*ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10)
```

<sub>Честно украдено с [How do I strip out all non-numeric characters?](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/459758-how-do-i-strip-out-all-non-numeric-characters.html)</sub>

На русском (не проверял, перевел [по таблице](http://brusentsov.com/2009/12/27/3519)):

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(ПСТР(0&A1,НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(ИНДЕКС(ЕЧИСЛО(--ПСТР(A1,СТРОКА($1:$25),1))
*СТРОКА($1:$25),0),СТРОКА($1:$25))+1,1)*10^СТРОКА($1:$25)/10)
```

Comment: Круто. Не думал, что это получится одной формулой.

Answer (score 2):

Если число «лишних» символов ограничено, то можно использовать много вложенных «поставить» в формуле:

```
подставить( подставить(текст, ".", ""), "-", "" )
```

и так далее. Сколько символов, столько и «подставить».

Если нужно удалить все, кроме цифр, то помогут только макросы.
Внутри макроса как вариант можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
dim re as New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\\D"
re.replace( text, "" )
```